# latex/tabularx multcolumn and column width

Tags: tabularx

I was reading the tabularx documentation and stumbled over a few things unclear to me.

1. In 4.3. Point 1 suggests that the the sum (of the fractions before `\hsize`) should always  be the number of columns used. Will it do any harm if this does not fit (except that if you calculated the numbers in advance, the columns width won't exactly fit the calculation (I'm asking just, because sometimes you do the maths but then you think that one column should be a bit bigger, so one just want to increase that one number instead of recalculating everything))
2. In 4.3. Point 2: What is meant by crossing? Should one have no multicolumn `[lXl]` (going over the left and right bound of a `X` column), `[XX]` (spanning over multiple `X` columns) or even `[lX]` (contain a `X` column)? - And why is that a problem, when the size does not fit, the package will just recalculate the sizes (from my understanding)
3. Why should `\hsize` be used to "weight" the column width and not another length like `\testwidht` or `\linewidth` (from what I know, they are somewhat similar (and on most occasions the same)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. tabularx really won't do anything sensible if you don't make the sizes add up. It does something and in some cases you may accept the result but any output in that case is accidental untested code paths
2. it means if you have an X column in column 2 you shouldn't have a `\multicolumn{..}{c}{...}`  which spans over column 2, but has no X. You can break this rule sometimes and sometimes you can't.  Details are a bit fuzzy 30 years after I wrote the code:-)
3. because you need to set `\hsize` as that is the tex primitive used for linebreaking widths. It's a good idea to set `\linewidth` to match (as shown in that item) so then nested latex lists will use the right length.

The reason (2) is a problem is that it essentially makes you violate (1).  If the width or a column declared as X is actually forced by an entry with a fixed natural length `\multicolumn{1}{c}{long text here}` then `tabularx` essentially ignores the X in that column and works as if there is one less X column in the table, and re-calulates. that's fine if it is X that was being spanned but if it was `>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X` then when this column is ignored and the number of active X columns is reduced the remaining modified widths will not meet the constraint set by (1).

Comment: 2. So `multicolumn` spanning over `XX` is ok, but over `Xr` is not good right (in general)?

Comment: @atticus I added some more words. It is spanning over X that is the problem, if that X has a modified hsize.

Comment: I understand now that there is a problem with that, but now I don't understand why this is not always a problem. If a `\multicolumn{2}{c}{text}` is spanning over `[XX]` (with normal `hsize`), then the two `X` are ignored and `tabularx` works as if there were two columns less in that table? (maybe some examples would help)

Comment: @atticus try some examples with `\tracingtabularx` set so the log shows what it is doing in each trial run (the answer to your question is yes) The X are not ifnored for typesetting but teh effective number of X columns is reduced.

Comment: I don't get it, I specify 2 columns in the tabularx preamble but in the output while compiling, `tabularx` does its first trial with 3 columns, is the first trial always with one more column? And when I have two `X`columns and a `multicolumn` spanning over therse two columns, `tabularx` still starts its first trial with 3 columns (this fails, 2 fails too and when reaching 1 some boundary is hit so it stops)... (I thought in that case it would calculare with a reduced number of columns?)

Comment: @atticus this really isn't how the site works, you can't keep asking subsidiary questions as comments. The tabularx doc says: % The number of {\ttfamily X} columns is set to one, which means that
% the initial count will be one too high, but this value is decremented
% before it is used in the main loop.

Comment: Yea, sorry it's just that I didn't want to make a new post of it since it's so close connected. Just one question on that (then if needed I'll make a new post): If the cell made by `multicolumn` does not exceed the original/fixed cell width is there then a problem too? (and is then too calculated with one less column?)